# C++ Conditional layout of class members

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, std

I want members of class to be rearranged based on template parameter

```
class Empty1 { };
class Empty2 { };
class Empty3 { };
class Empty4 { };
class Empty5 { };
class Empty6 { };

class Layout1 { public: uint32_t val1; float val2; bool val3; };
class Layout2 { public: uint32_t val1; bool val3; float val2; };
class Layout3 { public: float val2; uint32_t val1; bool val3; };
class Layout4 { public: float val2; bool val3; uint32_t val1; };
class Layout5 { public: bool val3; uint32_t val1; float val2; };
class Layout6 { public: bool val3; float val2; uint32_t val1; };

template<uint8_t I>
class Item :
    public std::conditional<(I % 6) == 0, Layout1, Empty1>::type,
    public std::conditional<(I % 6) == 1, Layout2, Empty2>::type,
    public std::conditional<(I % 6) == 2, Layout3, Empty3>::type,
    public std::conditional<(I % 6) == 3, Layout4, Empty4>::type,
    public std::conditional<(I % 6) == 4, Layout5, Empty5>::type,
    public std::conditional<(I % 6) == 5, Layout6, Empty6>::type
{
public:
    uint32_t getVal1() const { return val1; }
    float getVal2() const { return val2; }
    bool getVal3() const { return val3; }
};
```

This example should produce different order of val1,val2,val3 and therefore different memory layout on different value of I
All all the members exists in any case, but I keep getting error C3861 in visual studio even without usage of class
How can I fix it, or maybe someone know another way to do it?

#### GCC Error Messages

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘uint32_t Item<I>::getVal1() const’:
prog.cpp:28:39: error: ‘val1’ was not declared in this scope
     uint32_t getVal1() const { return val1; }
                                       ^~~~
prog.cpp: In member function ‘float Item<I>::getVal2() const’:
prog.cpp:29:36: error: ‘val2’ was not declared in this scope
     float getVal2() const { return val2; }
                                    ^~~~
prog.cpp: In member function ‘bool Item<I>::getVal3() const’:
prog.cpp:30:35: error: ‘val3’ was not declared in this scope
     bool getVal3() const { return val3; }
                                   ^~~~
```

Comment: "*getting error C3861*" Which is what, exactly?

Comment: It is "Identifier not found", but I don't even understand why compiler trying to compute members while don't know template yet... I tried to compile on C++ shell and getting similar error "was not declared in this scope"

Comment: *Which* identifier? You got a line number, so you should know which identifier it cannot find.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I didn't explainted that, compiler thinks that val1,val2,val3 not declared, while it will always be inherited from any of LayoutX, and error appears even if there only one conditional for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with dependent base classes. Because the base class(es) of the template depend on the template parameters, the base class names are dependent names. When that happens, the compiler cannot easily know if the name `val1` is being inherited from a base class.

Therefore, you must *explicitly* qualify such names with the base class it inherits from. Of course, that's kind of hard because of the way you tried to implement this whole thing.

It would be much better to use containment rather than inheritance, since you're going to have to qualify the names anyway. And you don't need all those empty structs; you just need to select from a type-list:

```
struct Layout1 { std::uint32_t val1; float val2; bool val3; };
struct Layout2 { std::uint32_t val1; bool val3; float val2; };
struct Layout3 { float val2; std::uint32_t val1; bool val3; };
struct Layout4 { float val2; bool val3; std::uint32_t val1; };
struct Layout5 { bool val3; std::uint32_t val1; float val2; };
struct Layout6 { bool val3; float val2; std::uint32_t val1; };

//The tuple is here just as a convenient type-list mechanism.
using LayoutList = std::tuple<Layout1, Layout2, Layout3, Layout4, Layout5, Layout6>;

template<uint8_t I>
struct Item
{
    using DataType = std::tuple_element_t<I % 6, LayoutList>;

    DataType val;

    uint32_t getVal1() const { return val.val1; }
    float getVal2() const { return val.val2; }
    bool getVal3() const { return val.val3; }
};
```

However, you can use similar type-list if you absolutely must use a base class:

```
template<uint8_t I>
using ItemDataType = std::tuple_element_t<I % 6, LayoutList>;

template<uint8_t I>
struct Item : ItemDataType<I>
{
    uint32_t getVal1() const { return ItemDataType<I>::val1; }
    float getVal2() const { return ItemDataType<I>::val2; }
    bool getVal3() const { return ItemDataType<I>::val3; }
};
```

Comment: Well, looks like there no error if make conditional part as member of class instead of inherit from it. Also it's interesting approach with tuple. Anyway your answer is correct, thank you!